# Package react-native-reanimated doesn't find

Tags: react-native

I have a detection problem on my react-native-reanimated package, I don't understand why it tells me it can't find the package.
The package is well in node-module, when I try to reinstall it manually it tells me that:

'' Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-reanimated` from file `C:\Users\augla\Dev\seducia-app\node_modules\@react-navigation\drawer\src\views\Drawer.tsx`, the package `C:\Users\augla\Dev\seducia-app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\augla\Dev\seducia-app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated`. Indeed, none of these files exist:  * C:\Users\augla\Dev\seducia-app\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx) ''

Thx for watching

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

> yarn start --reset-cache